# Insert many row to DatagridView using Multiple threads C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datagridview

I'm doing scrap program from website. I have many threads to update info to datagridview. I'm using dataset to set binding source to datagridview. When i inserted about 100k row. My GUI program show "not responding". I don't know how to solve it. This is my delegate to insert :

```
public void InsertLine(string line)
{
  this.MyDV.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {                 
    string[] park = Regex.Split(line, @",");
    try
    {
        //Insert new row
        MyDatasset.MyTableRow row = this.MyDataSet.MyTable.NewMyTableRow();
        row.Message = park[0].Trim();
        row.From = park[1].Trim();              
        this.MyDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Add(row);

        //Set color text for new row
        DataGridViewRow myrow = (from DataGridViewRow r in MyDV.Rows
                                 where (long)r.Cells[clId.Name].Value == row.Id
                                 select r).FirstOrDefault();
        if (myrow != null)
        {
            myrow.Cells[clFrom.Name].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            myrow.Cells[clMessage.Name].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }       
    }
    catch { }
    try
    {
        this.MyDV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.MyDV.Rows[this.MyDV.Rows.Count - 2].Index; //Scroll to lastest row
    }
    catch { }       
}));  }
```

Can you guys help me? I'm getting confused many hours with it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: does it go non-responsive for a period of time, or conclusively? i'm not sure how memory intensive adding 100k rows to a datagrid would be..

Comment: Yes, It is non-responsive, I open TaskManager and see that memory is  rising very fast from 34.000k to 144.000k on short time.

Comment: Why on earth would you need to display 100k+ rows in a DataGridView at the same time?

Comment: I need to export to .txt file. Before users can delete rows that they don't need or they also need to insert manually row. So i need to show all rows for users

Comment: That does not make sense much, display 100K+ rows will block your UI thread actually, why exporting stuff to txt file relating to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is invoking that code on the UI thread.  It's a loop that iterates potentially *many* rows.  This is probably taking a long time and blocking the UI thread from doing anything else.  You could try breaking up the work into smaller (or fixed-size) chunks and individually invoking them--which would allow the UI thread to process other messages in between.

Alternatively, you could do the work in the `Application.Idle` event; but, you'd likely still have to break up the work into fixed-sized chunks because you should only take a small, ideally fixed, amount of time in the `Idle` event.

Comment: Your mean that i need to break up to small bit code. Example: 
        MyDatasset.MyTableRow row = this.MyDataSet.MyTable.NewMyTableRow();
        row.Message = park[0].Trim();
        row.From = park[1].Trim();                 this.MyDV.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  { //add row here } .... blabla..  Sorry about EN

Comment: Actually, you're using FirstOrDefault to get a single row.  "Breaking" up the work might be a simple as running the LINQ code in a background thread (it's probably taking a while) and doing the rest on the UI thread (which you'd *have* to do).  I'm not sure whether DataGridView.Rows can be invoked on a non-UI thread, so verify that first or test to make sure it doesn't throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem that you have here is that you are not locking the code above and it is been accessed by multiple threads all at the same time.

You need to use :-

```
Lock (this)

{

this.MyDV.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate()
  {                 
    string[] park = Regex.Split(line, @",");
    try
    {
        //Insert new row
        MyDatasset.MyTableRow row = this.MyDataSet.MyTable.NewMyTableRow();
        row.Message = park[0].Trim();
        row.From = park[1].Trim();              
        this.MyDataSet.MyTable.Rows.Add(row);

        //Set color text for new row
        DataGridViewRow myrow = (from DataGridViewRow r in MyDV.Rows
                                 where (long)r.Cells[clId.Name].Value == row.Id
                                 select r).FirstOrDefault();
        if (myrow != null)
        {
            myrow.Cells[clFrom.Name].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
            myrow.Cells[clMessage.Name].Style.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        }       
    }
    catch { }
    try
    {
        this.MyDV.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = this.MyDV.Rows[this.MyDV.Rows.Count - 2].Index; //Scroll to lastest row
    }
    catch { }       
}));  }

}
```

This should make each thread wait in turn to use your insert delegate.

Also check out :- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: I know, i have only set one thread for each time. Threads is access sequential  to datagridviews. So "lock" isn't solve my problem. My problem is datatable inserted a large of rows. I'm trying virtual mod in datagridview but not working.